# Create inputs dinamically and retrieve their values to send via Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a help.
I have to create dynamically input (type text) for all cycles of forEach, after I need to send them via ajax request, I thought to this solution but it seems too messy, and also I don't know how to develop it until the end.. other solutions more easy? or advice to how fix mine?

Here the code:

```
function visualizzaModifica(array, div)
{
    div.html("");
    div.append("<br>");

    let i=1;

    array.forEach(function (e)
    {
        div.append
        (
            "<div class='input-group'>"+
            "<input type='text' id='inputModificaNome"+i+"' class='form-control' value='"+e.nominativo+"'>"+
            "<input type='text' id='inputModificaCellulare"+i+"' class='form-control' value='"+e.cellulare+"'>"+
            "</div>"
        );

        i++;
    });

    div.append
    (
        "<div class='input-group'>"+
        "<input type='text' id='inputModificaNome"+i+"' class='form-control'>"+
        "<input type='text' id='inputModificaCellulare"+i+"' class='form-control'>"+
        "</div>"
    );

    div.append("<br>");
    div.append("<button id='btnSalvaTeamLeaderProduzione' class='btn btn-secondary'>Salva</button>");
}

$("#divTeamLeaderProduzione").on("click","#btnSalvaTeamLeaderProduzione", function ()
{

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/updateTeamLeaderProduzione",
        type: "post",
        data:
            {
                nome1: $("#inputModificaNome1").val(),
                cellulare1: $("#inputModificaCellulare1").val(),
                nome2: $("#inputModificaNome2").val(),
                cellulare2: $("#inputModificaCellulare2").val(),

                HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PASS TO DATA THE NUMBER INDEFINITE
                OF VALUES

            },

        success: function ()
        {
            alert("Ok")
        },

        error: function (msg)
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  nome1: $("#inputModificaNome1").val(),
  cellulare1: $("#inputModificaCellulare1").val(),
  nome2: $("#inputModificaNome2").val(),
  cellulare2: $("#inputModificaCellulare2").val(),
}
```

you can do

```
var obj = {};



for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  obj[`nome{i+1}`] = $(`#inputModificaNome{i+1}`).val();
  obj[`cellulare{i+1}`] = $(`#inputModificaCellulare{i+1}`).val();
}
```